# Adding pause, next and previous buttons to jquery slider with progress bar

Tags: jquery, slider

I found [this simple slider](http://jsfiddle.net/jp9c1xj3/2/) with a progress bar. It works fine but I would like to add next, previous and pause buttons to it. Can anyone help?

**JS**

```
bar = $('.progress_bar');
time = 3000;

function run(){
    bar.width(0);
    bar.fadeIn(500,function(){
        bar.animate({'width': "100%"}, time).fadeOut(500,function(){
            change();run();
        });
    });
}
$("#slideshow > li:gt(0)").hide();


var change = function() { 
  $('#slideshow > li:first')
    .fadeOut(1000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(1000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
};

run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a codepen.io example which addresses the pause and continue functionality which I think is the more challenging part.  For the next, you would simply have a click event which would execute the change() function in your original example: http://codepen.io/KAPastor/pen/ezdQPd

```
<button id="run">RUN</button>  
<button id="pause">PAUSE</button>  
<button id="continue">CONTINUE</button>  

<div class="progress_bar"></div>
```

CSS

```
div.progress_bar {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #6cecc6;
    height: 5px;
    width: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1002;
    width: 100%;
     }
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#run').click(function(){
    $('.progress_bar').width(0);
    $('.progress_bar').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.progress_bar').animate({'width': "100%"},    3000)
  });
  });

    $('#pause').click(function(){
      $('.progress_bar').clearQueue();
    $('.progress_bar').stop();

  });

  $('#continue').click(function(){
$('.progress_bar').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.progress_bar').animate({'width': "100%"},    3000)
     });
  });



})
```

I know it is a simplified solution but I think it will be helpful!
Let me know if you have anymore questions.
-K

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful. I made a slight change on your code as the slider was not changing after pressing the pause and continue buttons. I simply added the change() and run() functions to the continue() function and that seemed to work. However it still doesn't appear to be working correctly with multiple slides. The pause and continue buttons work on the first slide but from the second slide onward they appear to do nothing..

Comment: Hey R.J,  glad I can help.  Is it possible for you to post a link to a jsfiddle or codepen of the solution/problem you just posted?  It would help me work off of your example :D

Comment: I just found what I was doing wrong. It was an issue with where I had the buttons. The way I had it initially, the script was appending new buttons with each slide which was causing them to not work after the first one. I moved the buttons out of the append and it seems to be working perfectly now. Thank you for the help Kyle :D